# Adding a list to Ext.Menu in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a sliding menu that I need to add buttons to dynamically from a JSON feed. You can see the current static button `var items`, but I am new to Sencha and I am having a lot of trouble researching this particular holdup. Thanks

```
Ext.define('AIN.view.SlideNavigation', {
requires: ['Ext.Menu'],
singleton: true,
constructor: function(config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
},
setMenu: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.createMenu('left'), {
        side: 'left',
        reveal: true
    });

    Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.createMenu('right'), {
        side: 'right',
        reveal: true
    });
},

createMenu: function(side) {
    var items = [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Green',
            iconCls: 'star',
            scope: this,
            handler: function() {
                AIN.container.setActiveItem(2);
                Ext.Viewport.hideMenu(side);
            }
        }
    ];

    var className = 'Ext.Menu';

    return Ext.create(className, {
        items: items
    });
}
});
```

My store is very simple and looks like this.

```
Ext.define('AIN.store.Channels', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',

config: {
    model: 'AIN.model.Channels',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://awebsite.com/app-feeds/channel-list',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'terms',
            record: 'term'
        }
    },
} 
});
```

Thank you

**Update** my data view.

```
Ext.define('AIN.view.MyDataView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'channellist',
config: {
    defaultType: 'mylistitem',
    useComponents: true
},
});
```

When I put these two lines in a NavigationView the list is created perfectly

```
xclass: 'AIN.view.MyDataView',
store: 'TestStore'
```

But when I add them to the Ext.Menu above, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the DataItem class with the useComponents config on dataviews - there's extensive docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/dataview (section "Component Dataview")

Comment: Thank you, I am very close to getting this now.

Comment: No worries, this stuff is a particularly steep learning curve! Only just getting the hang of it myself. The configs are important to data items

Comment: Hey shepsii, I added an update to my post above. I got the dataview component list working nicely, but can't get anything to show up in the Ext.Menu. Thanks

Comment: Try changing the layout of the Ext.Menu to "fit" in the config, ie:

    config: {
        layout: 'fit'
    }

 As an aside, if you're following best practice, your dataview should require the class of your dataitem type.